# Why can't I ask a question on meta after a ban?

Tags: discussion, suspension

I tried to ask a question on meta after a site ban was lifted, but I was greeted with this page.

[image]

Comment: ... did you just post a question on meta... asking why.. you couldn't post a question on meta?

That's meta.

Comment: @KyloRen - Having gotten yourself chat-banned after just a few minutes back on the site and having now immediately gotten into an argument with two different site users, may I politely suggest (and with the greatest amount of friendly and positive vibes) that your shut your mouth before you get yourself banned again. Take a day to think about how you want to interact with the site.

Comment: @KyloRen - Almost your first action in chat was to post a message laden with swearwords. What were you *expecting* to happen?

Comment: @Valorum, what swear words

Comment: @KyloRen - I believe your exact words were that "***Floofs suck balls***". And if you don't know that that's inappropriate for polite discourse, you may need to have a good hard think about what you say in public.

Comment: @Valorum, and that is considered a swear word? What are we in pre-school here?

Comment: @KyloRen - Let the fact that your post attracted 7 "abusive language" flags be your guide.

Comment: @Valorum, so it is the users that decide what is abusive then. I could say, "The cat sat in a hat" and if 7 people said that was abusive , it would be so then.

Comment: @KyloRen - I find it unlikely that 7 users would flag that as abusive but if they did, then yes, you'd attract an automatic ban. You could, however appeal it using the [contact us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) facility (or by flagging a moderator with a custom flag) and they'd unban you straight away and might consider banning those users who'd flagged you inappropriately.

Comment: @Valorum, why bother. This site is so inconsistent it is not funny.

Comment: Down-voting due to lack of research.

Answer (score 13):

I think as is often to blame... [the issue is caching...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/slow-update-of-reputation)

It takes about 10 minutes for reputation to catch back up.

It seems this has now been resolved as you have posted a question both on the main site and on meta.

Comment: But , I could post a questiion on the main site , but not on meta?

Comment: You can post a question on main with only 1 rep.

Comment: No I can't!!!!!

Comment: [But, you did?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LV1S.jpg)